# How to submit twice using InvokeMember("Click")

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, winforms-to-web

I write a program using WinForm with a Webbrowser Control. And if i click the button it should reply the Post or the Topic in Forum twice or many times. However, it only works once, and I don't know why it runs like this.
And here is the code in C# , and they are in method 
*private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)*

```
while (maxTimes > 0)
{
    while (true)
    {

        if (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            HtmlDocument document = this.webBrowser1.Document;
            HtmlElement htmlTextarea = document.GetElementById("fastpostmessage");
            htmlTextarea.SetAttribute("value", content);

            document.GetElementById("fastpostsubmit").InvokeMember("Click");

            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //Application.DoEvents(); 
            break;
        }
    }


    maxTimes--;
}
```

Every time, I click the button, it only replies once, no matter the value of *maxTimes*. And if I click again. It could reply, but only once. I tried to find out the reason. Could anyone here could help me? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does it reply multiple times when you click on it manually multiple times?

Comment: I mean when I click once, it only replies once, and if I click multiple times, it replies multiple times.And I want it runs like this, I click once, it replies multiple times.